# Custom httpErrors does not preserve BadRequest message

Tags: api, iis, proxy, asp.net-mvc-5, url-rewriting

I have a problem, the situation is as follows: I have some kind of proxy where I use Url rewrite to rewrite requests to RESTful api. There are situations, that api sends response BadRequest with 400 status code and message that tells what is wrong. When i call directly to api the message is returned as it should. And my problem is that when I call the same api but through that proxy i only get - 400 'BadRequest'.
I have a httpErrors section in my proxy config web:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
   <remove statusCode="403" />
   <remove statusCode="404" />
   <remove statusCode="500" />
   <error statusCode="403" responseMode="_path_" path="ExecuteUrl" />
   <error statusCode="404" responseMode="_path_" path="ExecuteUrl" />
   <error statusCode="500" responseMode="_path_" path="ExecuteUrl" />
</httpErrors>
```

I thought that problem lies in this custom error pages but i did not see here a page or custom error for 400 status code but i tried, and when i remove this or set existingResponse to

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough">
```

I can see my bad request message coming from api through proxy.
I am using IIS 7.5. I read somewhere that I even cannot set custom page for 400 status code response.

So what is going on ? Can I somehow solve my problem using "clean" solution, without any hacks?

I was trying

```
<remove statusCode="400" />
```

too.

I read somewhere about setting an existingResponse to "Auto" and about using flag 'TrySkipIisCustomErrors' but"Auto" response turned off every of my custom pages for other status codes, and 'TrySkipIisCustomErrors' - using this flag would require additional logic that I would like to avoid, I even do not know if this flag could help me.
Maybe some of You had similar situation and get rid of this problem?

Comment: If your intention is to see the raw error message on the client, then set error mode to detailed errors. This way no matter what the error is, you will see the original error message with call stack and stuff !

Comment: My intention is not to see the raw message on the client but to see error message ONLY for 400 status code, for any other code i want to see my custom message which i set in httpErrors.